# Analog of Hong Kong grade level for Chinese characters?

Tags: characters, mainland-china, reference-materials

The [Unihan database](http://www.unicode.org/charts/unihan.html) lists a [`kGradeLevel`](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/index.html#kGradeLevel) for each entry. This is the primary grade in the Hong Kong school system by which a student is expected to know the corresponding character.

Is there a similar categorization of characters into grade levels that applies to all of China (PRC)?

Comment: If you're looking for levels for Chinese as a second language look at hsk for simplified and top for traditional

Comment: @50-3 Thanks, I'm aware of HSK but am looking for something that may be in official or at least wide-spread use in the Chinese indigenous school system. BTW, do you know where one can obtain official vocabulary lists for HSK (from a reference book or, better, online source)?

Comment: Yer you can find them under the following search ["hsk level spreadsheet site:lingomi.s3.amazonaws.com"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=hsk+level+1+spreadsheet&oq=hsk+level+1+spreadsheet&aqs=chrome..69i57.7185j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=hsk+level+spreadsheet+site:lingomi.s3.amazonaws.com&safe=off)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about education adjustments' information instead of knowledge of Chinese language itself.

Comment: @CA55CE37 What is "education adjustments' information"? :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course we have, you can see it [on baidu.com](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/7ddd246ab84ae45c3b358cd5.html).

But because in China many provinces now have the right to have their own teaching syllabus, they may have different categorization of characters. But all the characters must come from the most common used 2500 characters. Then spread to the  other characters.